# Como carregar conteúdo em uma página de acordo com elemento clicado anteriormente?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma galeria simples onde cada imagem leva a uma nova página com sua descrição. Acontece que o layout de página para as descrições é o mesmo, só mudando o conteúdo. Como fazer para apenas alguns campos dessa página serem alterados de acordo com os itens clicados anteriormente na página da galeria?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Galeria</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href= "css/galeria.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_self" href="desc1.html">
      <img src="img/imagem1.jpg" alt="Imagem 1" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Imagem 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_self" href="desc2.html">
      <img src="img/imagem2.jpg" alt="Imagem 2" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Imagem 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_self" href="desc3.html">
      <img src="img/imagem3.jpg" alt="Imagem 3" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Imagem 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_self" href="desc4.html">
      <img src="img/imagem4.jpg" alt="Imagem 4" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Imagem 4</div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Recomendo você usar um _framework_ para isso, vai te ajudar muito. Tem o Angular 1.x, Knockout.. entre outros mais fáceis de aprender. Dá pra fazer o que você quer utilizando jQuery, mas é um pouco mais trabalhoso.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando para fazer sua galeria, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Acrescentei o código. Ainda sou bem iniciante nesse assunto, a galeria é bem simples. O problema é ter que fazer desc1.html, desc2.html, desc 3.html... para cada descrição. Para galerias maiores, gostaria de saber como fazer para usar um mesmo html e carregar as informações correspondentes ao que foi clicado lá.

Comment: Dei esta resposta neste [Como abrir uma div específica em outra página?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187458/62465)

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção seria passar por parâmetro na URL, no exemplo passei o ID do item.

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemGaleria', function() {
    var itemGaleria = $(this).attr('id');
    if (itemGaleria ) {
        window.location = '/outra_pagina?item=' + itemGaleria;
    }
});​
```

E na "outra_pagina" tu pode pegar o valor do parâmetro com a seguinte função:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Assim:

```
var itemGaleria = getParameterByName('item'); // "id do item"
```

Answer (score 0):

Como eu já respondi neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187458/62465).

Não tem como eu botar um só fiddle funcional aqui porque involve mais de uma página, então vou criar dois htmls + um js e você pode simular fazendo os seguintes arquivos na mesma pasta. Veja no passo-a-passo:

### Primeiro Arquivo - index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="selector.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      initSectorUI();

      $("#navigator a").click(function() {
        showSectorMini($(this).attr('href'));
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .block {
      width: 100%;
      height: 33vh;
    }
    
    #first {
      background: red;
    }
    
    #second {
      background: blue;
    }
    
    #third {
      background: green;
    }
    
    #fourth {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    #fifth {
      background: pink;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navigator">
    <a href="page.html#first">First</a>
    <a href="page.html#second">Second</a>
    <a href="page.html#third">Third</a>
    <a href="page.html#fourth">Fourth</a>
    <a href="page.html#fifth">Fifth</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Segundo Arquivo - page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="selector.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      initSectorUI();

      $("#navigator a").click(function() {
        showSectorMini($(this).attr('href'));
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .block {
      width: 100%;
      height: 33vh;
    }
    
    #first {
      background: red;
    }
    
    #second {
      background: blue;
    }
    
    #third {
      background: green;
    }
    
    #fourth {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    #fifth {
      background: pink;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sectors">
    <div id="first" class="block" style="display: none;">A</div>
    <div id="second" class="block" style="display: none;">B</div>
    <div id="third" class="block" style="display: none;">C</div>
    <div id="fourth" class="block" style="display: none;">D</div>
    <div id="fifth" class="block" style="display: none;">E</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <form><input Type="button" VALUE="Voltar" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></form>
</body>

</html>
```

### Terceiro Arquivo - selector.js

```js
var initSectorUI = function() {
  if (location.hash) showSectorMini(location.hash);
};

var showSectorMini = function(sector) {
  $('#sectors > div').hide();
  $(sector).show();
};
```

Junte os três arquivos em uma pasta e me diga se funcionou. Aqui foi de boas! :)